# Get List of Formatted Strings

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I would like to get a list of strings in the following format:

```
["00:00", "00:01", ..., "23:58", "23:59"]
```

How can I do this with Python?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

List comprehension:

```
["{0:02d}:{1:02d}".format(a,b) for a in range(24) for b in range(60)]
```

Will produce a list of

```
['00:00', '00:01', '00:02', ..., '23:57', '23:58', '23:59']
```

Answer (score 2):

```
["{0:02d}:{1:02d}".format(a,b) for a in range(24) for b in range(60)]
```

produces

```
["00:00", "00:01", ..., "23:58", "23:59"]
```

This solves the problem with a list comprehension

Comment: I'd like to suggest that you include both variables in the format, and remove the `0` from the range calls.  Then you'd have my answer :)

Comment: Yea I was going to fix that and then you posted :(

Comment: Don't want to copy